# Calling of an .sql file existing on the server from the Database oracle (using PLSQL)

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am using the following code to run scripts from DB in a store procedure, but it returns failure(RESULT = -1):

```
RESULT := RUN_COMMAND ('sqlplus usrname/'|| PSSWD||'@'||DB_NAME ||' @'||file_path||'/'||file_name||'_'||seq||'.sql');
```

The RUN_COMMAND function is written as follow:

```
create or replace function RUN_COMMAND(in_cmd in varchar2) return number
as
language java
name 'UTIL_CMD.RunThis(java.lang.String) return integer';
```

To note that the variable passed in the function RUN_COMMAND is executing successfully if running on the server (using putty).

In addition, the RUN_COMMAND is functional with other passed in parameters,
for example run_command('chmod 777 -R ....')

For that please help me figure out what's going wrong by executing the procedure from PLSQL.

Comment: try using full path for the "sqlplus" command?

Comment: You mean what by full path of the sqlplus command? Thank you

Comment: What error do you get?